# What do you call this "metal" clotheline?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call this kind of clotheslines?

[image]

Source: http://righthere2014.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-194.html

(They are often used in Japan and other Asian countries.)

Comment: I'd call that a "clothes rod".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps "a (hanging) (clothes) rack"

e.g. "I saw a pair of trousers on the rack in my size."

Comment: Your example seems to be about clothes in a shop. The example picture is drying clothes on a balcony. Your answer probably needs further explanation as to how these are the same. Also (as noted on one of your other answers) please consider including a dictionary definition with a link to it, where appropriate and possible.